# Numerical Integral of a product of Error function and Exponential function

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to evaluate the integral of the expression below. It involves a product of the error function (Erf) and the exponential function (Exp). However, the following error appears and the integral does not evaluate. What may be the issue here.

```
NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand (E^(-(1/24) (5.09389 +<<1>>/<<1>>)^2) 
(1+Erf[(-4+(10 Log[Times[<<2>>]])/Log[<<1>>])/(2 Sqrt[6])]))/z has evaluated 
to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with 
boundaries {{\[Infinity], {0,0.04148193194,0.2550389316,1.354471624,7.014563526,36.15381013,186.1682812,95 8.4717599,4934.439273}}}.




  cth = Range[0, 8, 1]; 
  d1 = 1; 
  d2 = 1; 
  nu = 0.4; 
  ps = 1; 
  h1mu = 2; 
  h2mu = 2; 
  h1sigma = 3; 
  h2sigma = 3; 
  eta = 10/Log[10]; 
  alpha = 0.154; 
  rho = 0.581; 
  m = 2.7; 
  rsigma = 0.01; 
  dsigma = 0.01; 
  a1 = 2*nu*alpha*ps; 
  a2 = (1 - alpha)*d1^m*d2^m*dsigma; 
  a3 = 2*nu*alpha*d1^m*rsigma; 
  v = 2^((2*cth)/(1 - alpha)) - 1; 
  gamma = (v*a2)/(z - v*a3); 
  intvalue = (1/z)*(1 + Erf[(eta*Log[gamma] - 2*h2mu)/(2*Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[h2sigma])])*
   Exp[-((eta*Log[z] - (2*h1mu + eta*Log[a1]))^2/(8*h1sigma))]; 
  nonoutage = ((eta/(4*Sqrt[8*Pi*h1sigma]))*NIntegrate[#1, {z, (v*a3)/a1, Infinity}, 
          WorkingPrecision -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 6, 
   MaxRecursion -> 100] & ) /@ intvalue; 
  outage = 1 - nonoutage;
```

Comment: Check the integration limits: `(v*a3)/a1` should be a scalar not a list!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann The lower limit is a list. How can I write the correct syntax for it?

Comment: The lower limit must be a scalar. The correct syntax would be `NIntegrate[#1, {z, (v*a3/a1)[[3]], Infinity}` for the third(examplary) list element .

Comment: @UlrichNeumann So I decided to try the integral with just one value for the lower limit as you suggested. However, I still get the following error `NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small``NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in z near {z} = {8.16907*10^224}. NIntegrate obtained 191611.98680708188` and 160378.51781028943` for the integral and error estimates.`

Comment: You are using `WorkingPrecision` wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question right , you try to solve a list of different integrands `intvalue` in a range from lower limit (given by a corresponding list `(v*a3)/a1` to `Infinity`.

**First observation:** `intvalue[[1]] (* Indeterminate*)`

You should define all the parameters `nu,alpha,rho,m,rsigma,dsigma` with "infinite accuracy", for example

```
rho = Rationalize[0.581,0];
```

Now you can evaluate the integrals one by one:

```
Table[NIntegrate[intvalue[[i]], { z, ((v*a3)/a1)[[i]] , Infinity}], {i, 1,Length[intvalue]}]
(*{0., 0.0103759, 0.0762758, 0.00791823, 0.000014209, 4.16319*10^-10,1.90864*10^-16, 1.33846*10^-24, 1.41807*10^-34}*)
```